# Why setting Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder would just do renaming but not switching?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm using Outlook 2010, and in VBA I was trying,

```
Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderRssFeeds)
```

It just renamed current folder with the name "Rss Feeds", this is not right as it suppose to switch to the rss feeds folder. But it seems the only way to switch folders in Outlook VBA, and I couldn't find any explanation in help document that it will do renaming instead of switching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed out the keyword `Set`

It should be 
`Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderRssFeeds)`

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866719.aspx

Comment: @Larry +1 for you. And [is this just useful or brilliant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148066/can-i-search-my-comments-using-some-keywords)? In a quest of getting a great feature :)